# Search won't work on hash table

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I can't figure out why my search code won't work in hash table. I already tried inserting printf on every line just to see the flow of code and it was right, but I still can't seem to get the right output. This program saves words on hashtable alphabetically and it uses linked list. So if I search a word that starts with 'A' it must return Key:1 and so on. I'll appreciate any help you can give :)

```
void searchInHash(int key, char *name) {
    int hashIndex = key, flag = 0;
    struct node *myNode;
    myNode = hashTable[hashIndex].head;
    if (!myNode) {
        printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");
        return;
    }
    while (myNode != NULL) {
        if (myNode == name) {
            printf("Key: %d\n", hashIndex);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        myNode = myNode->next;
    }
    if (!flag)
       printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `f (myNode == name) {` : type of `myNode`  is `struct node*`. type of `name` is `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name is a `char*` pointer.
myNode is a `struct node*` pointer.

They can't be ***equal***, which means, have the same memory address.

`myNode == name` will always be false.

If you want to compare the *content* pointed at by the pointers, you can use string.h function `strcmp()` instead. See : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

But be sure that both pointers do point at an actual string (null terminated). It's fine for `name`, but probably not regarding `myNode`.

Comment: @gaily : the habit is to validate an answer (left side check box) when you feel it answers your question.